# How Apple's pro apps force the "graphite" look?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I was wondering how Apple's "Pro" apps (Final Cut Pro X, Compressor, etc) always display the "graphite" look, even when the user has "blue" set on system preferences.

Doing some investigation I found that the code that makes It happen is in a function called NSProApplicationMain. If I make a new Xcode project, link It to ProKit.framework and swap NSProApplicationMain instead of NSApplicationMain, the app gets the "graphite" look.

Anyone knows what makes this happen? Is there a system call or something?

Comment: It's a private framework, which means there will be no documentation for any of it's methods. Since it's just a framework you can just import it, but you'll want use an alternative if you want to put it on the app store.

Comment: Yeap I know that, I just wonder whether anyone knows what's the call that makes an app adopt the graphite look, so I can do It without using the private framework. It's more of a curiosity thing, I don't plan to use It in production software...

Comment: You just.. import it as a framework. Link the framework from the directory of the framework, `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProKit.framework`, and then import it to your classes with `#import <ProKit/Prokit.h>`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you're writing a plug-in, there may be API to make your plug-in's custom UI fit in with the rest of the application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figured It out, It is really simple and doesn't involve the use of a private API:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setVolatileDomain:@{@"AppleAquaColorVariant": @6} forName:NSArgumentDomain];
```

I've discovered It by disassembling the ProKit framework that comes with the new iMovie ;)

Edit: The code above has to be run before UIApplicationMain.

Comment: can you elaborate? does not seem to do anything when put into the applicationDidFinishLaunching: method of a new app on 10.13

Comment: You have to run this before UIApplicationMain. I added it to main.m.

Comment: There is no `UIApplicationMain` in `macOS`.

Answer (score 2):

ProKit implements that look itself. It's not relying on a built in graphite appearance in AppKit.

There's no supported way to use this appearance other than reimplementing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If want to have a similar look you will need to go with `NSBorderlessWindowMask` for now and reimplement a lot of subtlety. The traffic light buttons are bit of work to get right. Everything should change its appearance based on the window being key or main and the application being front most.
`NSAppearance` may turn into something useful in the future. Don't hold your breath waiting. 
Go and dally into the depths of `NSWindow`, `NSWindowController`, `NSView`, `NSViewController` and after that, the hard part comes with implementing all the other controls and views in your new style.

Comment: Yeah. You're going to want table and outline views. Not to mention a host if others...